# JS automatic transfer codes needs discussion

Tags: javascript

I got a piece of code that can help me redirect to a page automatically after a period of time. However, it doesn't work.

Could anybody take a look at it,and, if possible, modify it? Thanks!!

```
<body>

<a href="http://www.baidu.com" class="prevpage" id="lianjie">.......</a>
<script>
var dizhi = "";

function get() {
    var _el = document.querySelectorAll('#lianjie');
    var len = _el.length();
    if (len > 0) {
        dizhi = _el[0].href;
    }
}
onload = function() {
    get();
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.href = dizhi;
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: remove () after .length

Answer (score 1):

[`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) is a property and not a method, so:

```
var len = _el.length();
```

should actually be:

```
var len = _el.length;
```